# Embedded pdf in Bootstrap not full height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having a problem with my embedded pdf on this page. [sponsorships](http://portsmouthgreekfestival.com/sponsorship-1.html) The previous version of this site was html4 and embed was done with the object tag like this

```
  <object data="pdf/GreekFestSponsorship2013.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="700px"> 
  <p>It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser.</p>
  <p id="missing-pdf-plugin">You can <a href="pdf/GreekFestSponsorship2013.pdf">click here to download the PDF file</a>.</p>
  </object>
```

This is the new code

```css
/* Flexible iFrame */
 
.flexible-container {
    position: relative;
    
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
 
.flexible-container iframe,   
.flexible-container object,  
.flexible-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>Greek Festival Portsmouth NH</title>
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom CSS: You can use this stylesheet to override any Bootstrap styles and/or apply your own styles -->
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!-- Font Awesome JS -->
 <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a0aac8df13.js"></script>
<meta name="Description" content="Three fun-filled days in Portsmouth NH as the magic of Greece comes to town. The Glendi or party will begin on Friday, July 15th, July 16th and July 17th with authentic Greek food. We will offer live Greek music from the band orfeas and continual music by DJ Meleti. In addition to the food, there will be booths that will offer imported jewelry, arts and crafts from Greece. A children's play area will ensure the entire family enjoys their virtual visit to this ancient land.">
<meta name="Keywords" content=" st. nicholas greek orthodox church, nicholas in greek, greek cuisine, st. nicholas greek orthodox cathedral, charleston food and wine, greek orthodox archdiocese, goarch.org, greek food festivals, st nicholas greek festival, greek food festival, wine events, orthodox christianity, food and wine events, wine tasting events, greek orthodox calendar, dallas greek festival, greek festival st. louis, st nick gift ideas, st nicholas greek orthodox, what to do in portsmouth nh, wine and food events, greek for church, greek orthodox religion, food and wine festival 2016, nicholas greek, st nicholas greek, st louis greek, festival seacoast online calendar, portsmouth events, orthodox music, greek orthodox christian, greek orthodox churches, greek orthodox music, greek orthodox christianity, greek festival st louis mo, greek dates, seacoast nh events, st nick gifts, greek orthodox icon, annunciation  ,greek orthodox wine event, orthodox greek food and wine festivals, 2016 food and wine event, church in greek, greek orthodox church ann arbor, famous greek foods, portsmouth high, charleston wine festival, live music in portsmouth nh, activities in portsmouth nh, greek orthodox faith, greek orthodox festival st nicholas, orthodox greek nicholas, food and wine tasting, food and wine shows, food and wine events 2016, moving to portsmouth nh, portsmouth nh food music festival july, portsmouth nh classifieds, greek food items, live music in nh, festival this weekend, festival of food, eastern orthodox music, greek orthodox religious items, glendi festival, music festival, vendors, where is portsmouth nh, portsmouth activities, saint nicholas orthodox, becoming greek orthodox, greek church, music, music festival dates,  greek orthodox bishop, orthodox children festival in july, greek orthodox food events in portsmouth, greek orthodox festivals, dates in greek, eastern orthodox new year, greek orthodox schools, food in portsmouth, music festival in july, beer, weekend wine activities, the greek orthodox, on line events, greek orthodox community, orthodox music  ">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/android-chrome-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/mstile-144x144.png">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
</head>
<body>
<div class="main-navigation-container navbar-fixed-top" id="primary-navbar">
            <nav class="navbar">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <!-- Mobile Toggle Button and stuff -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#primary-navigation" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="" title="PortsmouthGreekFestival.com">PortsmouthGreekFestival.com</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End of mobile toggle button -->
                    <!-- Start of the navbar -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="primary-navigation">
                        <ul class="nav  nav-justified">
                            <li><a href="index.html">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                           <li><a href="Menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                            <li><a href="photos.html">Photos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="events.html">Schedule of Events</a></li>
                            <li><a href="sponsors.html">Sponsors</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
</div>  
<header class="masthead">
      <img src="images/Banner.jpg" alt="Portsmouth Greek Festival Logo">
</header>     
<!-- /.container -->
<!-- Feature -->
<div class="container">

<h1>Sponsorship Opportunities</h1>
<div class="flexible-container-embed">
<object data="pdf/GreekFestSponsorship2013.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
   <p>This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: <a href="http://portsmouthgreekfestival.com/pdf/GreekFestSponsorship2013.pdf">Download PDF</a></p>
</object>
  
</div> </div>
<footer>    
<!-- Copyright etc -->
<div id="Copyright">
<p>Copyright &copy; <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> PortsmouthGreekFestival.com</p>
</div>
</footer>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- IE10 viewport bug workaround -->
<script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see how the pdf is not 100% height in this screenshot. 
[image: screenshot]

Comment: can you provide  a working fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You have 2 extra rulesets that'll work as intended **but** you need to...
2. ...correct this in HTML:

   > ```
   > <div class="flexible-container-embed"> to this:
   > <div class="flexible-container">
   > ```
3. ...and add this to `.flexible-container` CSS ruleset:

   > ```
   >  padding-bottom:100%`
   > ```
4. When adding those 2 rulesets, place them in a `<style>` element and then add that to be the last position inside the `<head>` element. Go to the Plunker link below for an example.

I think what happened is that you found the correct code to fix it, but while implementing it you didn't understand why certain properties and values looked so odd. For instance (sorry about the caps, the formatting is limited, I'm not yelling):

```
/* Flexible iFrame */

.flexible-container {
    position: relative;
    /* This blank line was probably:
    || padding-top: 56.25%;
    */
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* This ruleset says:
|| "Apply the following properties and their values to ANY `<iframe>`,
|| `<object>`, or `<embed>` THAT IS A CHILD OF any element with the 
|| class of `.flexible-container`.
*/
.flexible-container iframe,   
.flexible-container object, 
.flexible-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

When you applied these 2 rulesets, you had given the div that wraps the `<object>` the class of `.flexible-container-embed` but both rulesets apply to elements with the class of `.flexible-container` **and** any of it's children that are `<iframe>`, `<object>`, or `<embed>`.  Basically, remove the <del>-embed</del> part of the class name.

Next was the `padding-bottom` property. This is commonly at 56.25% which when applied to the container of an iframe the proper context to maintain a height of 9 to the width of 16. That's good for a wide screen format video, but not so good for a PDF which is probably has an aspect ratio of 8:11 or 72% (I used 100% in the demo since that's what you requested, expect an edit that'll include a 72% version.) If we combine the padding with the `height:0`, we get a container that acts like "shrinkwrap" that adapts it's height according to it's content's width. **Update**: there's no discernible change from 100% to 72% because of the padding the PDF plugin adds.

I changed the `<object>` into an `<iframe>` because they are more versatile, you can use `<embed>` as well. Review this [**<kbd>PLUNKER</kbd>**](http://embed.plnkr.co/Glz3EmR8CaKsCzGmEhl1/)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Glad I could be of help, sir.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite difficult display the PDF file in full 100% height. You may want to take Bootstrap's [responsive embedded media](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed) approach as the result is fairly decent and there's less hassle involved.

Results in Chrome:
[image: chrome embedded PDF]

Results in Firefox:
[image: firefox embedded PDF]

Source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PDF</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
            <object data="test.pdf" type="application/pdf">
                <p>
                    Your browser does not support embedded PDF files.<br>
                    <a href="test.pdf">Click here to
                    download the PDF file.</a>
                </p>
            </object>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please keep in mind that not all browsers support embedded PDF files, hence the notice inside the `<object>` tag.